# Berries poisonous for cats

Tags: cats, poison, plants

Are these berries poisonous for my cat? 
(no, he hasn't eaten any, but if they would be dangerous for him, I'd remove that Bush, just to make sure...)

[image: bush]

Comment: Cats aren't likely to eat any kind of berries, so I don't think I'd worry about it...

Comment: I'd suggest adding a gardening discussion to help you identify the bush -- it's off-topic here -- which will then let you look up it's toxicity and discuss it with your vet.

Comment: Do cats eat berries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24995/what-is-this-low-growing-bush-with-variegated-leaves-and-red-berries) I was told that this is a form of holly (ilex spp) [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holly) which is poisonous for both humans and cats, but like it was said here es well, cats are very unlikely to eat them.

Answer (score 1):

We had those berries in our yard,  as kids and were told never to eat them, and they never seemed to be a problem with any cats, including ours. We lived in a track and there were lots of cats. And remember a cat is a self survivor, so the are smart.